# How to stop PageSpeed from setting no-cache on my html page?

Tags: apache, caching, browser-cache, pagespeed

I am using Apache with PageSpeed; On my index page I want to manually set a cache time by PHP but the headers get overwritten by PageSpeed because it sees the page as html and it ads no-cache:

```
header("Cache-Control:public, max-age=60");
```

pagespeed modifies it to:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, s-maxage=10
```

From the [downstram caching](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/downstream-caching) documentation:

> By default PageSpeed serves HTML files with Cache-Control: no-cache,
>   max-age=0 so that changes to the HTML and its resources are sent fresh
>   on each request

OK, but is there an easy way to get rid of that `no-cache` ? The method shown on documentation seems insanely complicated for such a simple issue. And already having reverse proxies and such, the infrastructure is complicated enough already.
Would `Cache-Control:private` help ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders off` does just that, not sure why this is not mentioned in the [downstream caching documentation](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/downstream-caching).